# Using Around with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, around

I was trying to obtain the same result of a differential equation with to different methods the first one is based on `DSolve` and the second one is based on `NDSolve`

```
a = Around[1, 0.1];
b := DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == a, y[0] == a}, y[x], {x, 0, 1090}]
f[x_] = y[x] /. b[[1]];
f[2]
```

And with this code I get that $f[2]=1\pm  0.1018$.

Now I want to get the same result but using `NDSolve`:

```
soli = NDSolve[{p'[x] + p[x] == a, p[0] == a}, p[x], {x, 0, 1090}]
solie[x_] = p[x] /. soli[[1]];
solie[2]
```

But the Mathematica V.12 gives as result

```
NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition 1.00±0.10 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.
```

The problem is that I need to use `NDSolve` because I have a  complicated differential equation (not the equation that appears in the example)

Comment: I think you might have to integrate each end-point value separately (`ParametricNDSolve[]` could help with this).  Of course, you're not guaranteed to capture the full range of the trajectories, but I don't think `NDSolve` is programmed to do it either.

Comment: @Michael E2: The following soli = ParametricNDSolve[{p'[x] + p[x] == a, p[0] == a}, 
   p, {x, 0, 1090}, {a}];p1 = p[Around[1, 0.1]] /.  soli; p1[10] /. soli does not work for me in version 12.0 on Windows 10 32bit.

Comment: @user64494 Why would you think it would work?  I said "end-point" (i.e. a number), not `Around[..]`.

Comment: @Michael E2: I tried that, no more and no less.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) to analyse how sensitive the solution is to parameters or initial conditions. There are multiple examples on the reference page under "Scope".